# How can I use the scollTop function to enable smooth scrolling with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scrolltop, smooth-scrolling

I have created a custom "subnavbar" that sits under bootstrap's navbar. It's based on the code from wrapbootstrap.

I want to enable smooth scrolling using scrolltop. I have the following Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $('#subnav').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top});                                                         
        });
    });
```

However, I can't seem to make it work. Am I using the wrong # reference? Here is a bootply: http://bootply.com/62720

HTML snippet below:

```
                     <!-- Subnav bar -->                
                     <div class="subnav subnav-fixed">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                           <li><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#opening-hours">Opening hours</a></li>

                        </ul>
                     </div>
<section id="Overview">          
<h3>OVERVIEW</h3>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show demo of your problem on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple and easy mistake to make "#subnav" should be ".subnav a" firstly because subnav is the class and secondly because you want the click binded to the link

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work. This will set top to `0` when there is no offset()

```
$('.subnav li a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hashTag = this.hash;
    var top = 0;

    if ($(hashTag).offset()) {
        top = $(hashTag).offset().top
    }

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:top}, 'slow');                                                         
});
```

Here is the update: http://bootply.com/62723